# Flask: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'

Tags: python, flask

I have a strange error, that I never saw before.

I wrote a small http web server using flask and when I run I got the error bellow.

I am using virtual env and my python version is 3.8

What can be?

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print(request.get_json())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

````
python tools/fake.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/otc/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 58, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/fake.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/otc/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/otc/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/otc/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 61, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'```
````

Comment: are you using fresh virtualenv ? dont forget return value before print!

Comment: yes, fresh virtual env. I updated with my requirements.txt

Comment: can you provide requrements.txt so litle info, i can't figure

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Flask and werkzeug again

Comment: The requirements txt https://pastebin.com/raw/ZQ0Z7Fvv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the first traceback:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package
```

You need to rename the `http.py` file to something else because it is overriding the standard library `http` module. To fix it, you will need to do the following:

- Rename the file `http.py` to something else.
- Remove `.pyc` files in the project

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

- Run the program again

Python3 uses `socketserver`, all lowercase. Python2 uses `SocketServer`

Answer (score 0):

this maybe helps you
`

```
pip uninstall Flask

pip uninstall Werkzeug

pip install Flask

pip install Werkzeug
```

`